# Syntax Error in Boolean Null values

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, null, psql, csv

I have a csv that contains Boolean variables (yes,no,blanks). How can I recode blanks so that it'd integrate in the data type. Or fo i have to change data type for blanks to be readable?

Answer (score 1):

You can change how `COPY` represents NULL values.

For example, assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE hasbool (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   is_cool boolean,
   name text NOT NULL
);
```

I can use blanks to represent NULL as in the following `psql` session:

```
\pset null '∅'
Null display is "∅".

COPY hasbool FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv', NULL ' ');
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> 1,TRUE,joe
>> 2, ,paul
>> \.
COPY 2

TABLE hasbool;

 id │ is_cool │ name 
════╪═════════╪══════
  1 │ t       │ joe
  2 │ ∅       │ paul
(2 rows)
```